# How do you multiply a column vector with a row vector using @ in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I'm running the following Python code:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1,2])
b=np.array([3,4])
a@b #11
a.T@b #11
a@b.T #11
a.T@b.T #11
```

All four operations give the dot product. It was my understanding that `a` and `b` would be row vectors, so `a.T@b` would give a 2x2 matrix. What am I misunderstanding here and how do I matrix multiply the column vector of `a` with the row vector of `b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can see here, is a property of how numpy arrays and matrices work.
You've created numpy arrays, each 2 long, which if you transpose, you still get an array of length 2. You can see this if you do `a.shape`. You have to create a 1x2 matrix, where it will work as you expected:

```
>>> a=np.array([[1,2]])
>>> b=np.array([[3,4]])
>>> a@b
Error
>>> a.T@b
array([[3, 4],
       [6, 8]])
>>> a@b.T
array([[11]])
>>> a.T@b.T
Error
```

Comment: Ok thank you. When I do the dot product, I now get `[[11]]`. What if I just want to number itself, rather than the operation to output another 2x2 matrix?

Comment: You can use [np.asscalar](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asscalar.html)

Comment: Last point on this: I tried doing `np.array([[2,2],[2,2]])@np.array([3,3]).T`, which should output a column vector, but instead outputs a row vector. Do you know why this is?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [np.outer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) to get the outer product

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.array([1,2])
>>> b=np.array([3,4])
>>> np.outer(a, b)
array([[3, 4],
       [6, 8]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two dimensional arrays to represent matrices/matrix multiplication.

```
a = np.array([[1, 2]])
b = np.array([[3, 4]])
print(a.T @ b)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it is important to understand that your `a` and `b` are neither rows nor columns. They are 1D.

Matrix multiplying them only works because the `@` treats 1D operands specially. On the left they will be implicitly made a row, on the right a column. Dimensions added will be removed from the result. So a@b gives the inner product.

```
a@b
# 11
```

For the outer product, we need to build 2D vectors.
A convenient way of transforming two 1D vectors into a column and a row is `np.ix_`:

```
ac,br = np.ix_(a,b)

ac@br
# array([[3, 4],
#        [6, 8]])
```